# Mock Void type in Mockito

Tags: mockito

Say `Foo` is the class we mock and `Foo` has a method named `Foo.bar()` which returns type `Void` (not `void`). How can we use Mockito to mock this method?

Not sure whether returning `null` in this case would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [Void is final and not instantiable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html), there is no instance you could ever return. In production, that method can only return `null` (if it returns at all), and that should hold true in your tests as well.

Note that Mockito will [return `null` by default](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2) for methods that return Object instances other than collections and primitive wrappers, so you should only need to stub a method that returns Void if you need to override a spied method:

```
// Spy would have thrown exception
// or changed object state
doReturn(null).when(yourSpy).someMethodThatReturnsVoid();
```

Or throw an exception:

```
// Throw instead of returning null by default
when(yourMock.someMethodThatReturnsVoid()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

Or react with an Answer:

```
when(yourMock.someMethodThatReturnsVoid()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
  @Override public void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    // perform some action here
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi this answer is detailed and helpful. While I'm almost sure that unstubbed methods return null by default, is this documented anywhere in Mockito's documentation?

Comment: Glad to help! The default value docs are in [Mockito documention item 2](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2) (first bullet). You can also see where it happens in the [ReturnsEmptyValues source](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsEmptyValues.java).